# Hovered mini profile in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a list of users. When I move my mouse over each user, I want to show a mini profile.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[mini-profile-directive]',
  host: {
    '(mouseenter)': 'onMouseEnter($event)'
  }
})
export class MiniProfileDirective {
  private mouseEnter = new EventEmitter();

  onMouseEnter($event) {}
}
```

When I use, I use like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users" mini-profile-directive><div>
```

However, I want to show something, Directive cannot show something.

---

So I create a component.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[mini-profile-component]',
  host: {
    '(mouseenter)': 'onMouseEnter($event)'
  },
  template: ``
})
export class MiniProfileComponent {
  private mouseEnter = new EventEmitter();

  onMouseEnter($event) {
    // here won't run!
  }
}
```

Then use like this, which is wrong.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users" mini-profile-component></div>
```

---

A way comes into my mind is having both `MiniProfileDirective` and `MiniProfileComponent`

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users" mini-profile-directive><div>
<mini-profile-component></mini-profile-component>
```

Inside of `MiniProfileDirective`, use Service to control show/hide of the `MiniProfileComponent`.

Any better ways? Thanks

Comment: What do you want to show?

Comment: @yurzui there is a list of users. When you move your mouse over each user, show a mini profile.

Comment: You can use `renderer` to add eventlistener http://plnkr.co/edit/OPgHQKwlfJ2B46dgdUZH?p=preview But i don't understand why hostbinding within component doesn't work http://plnkr.co/edit/sy2vxwOJ58Ll2d32Sdkt?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui thanks!! I think you can create an answer, so I can accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

[**Example hovered profile component**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0MQ3PauM9mGzRIdOr2cJ?p=preview)

**Origin**

As an alternative of `host` binding you can use `listen` method of `Renderer` class like this:

```
constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
  renderer.listen(elementRef.nativeElement, 'mouseenter', (e) => this.onMouseEnter(e))
}
```

See the working plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/OPgHQKwlfJ2B46dgdUZH?p=preview

Comment: oh, I am excited too early. But then, in your demo, username 1, 2, 3 is gone. I want to add something(a hovered mini profile), not replace.

Comment: Then reproduce your solution. I want to know how you render users

Comment: If you don't want to replace content, you can use `ng-content`. See my updated answer

Comment: Wow, that is so perfect. Really appreciate your time!